# TS2339: Property 'username' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'. When using Cypress fixtures

Tags: jquery, typescript, cypress

I'm new to using TypeScript, I'm trying to convert my Cypress tests to TS but I'm having an issue whenever I'm reading from the fixtures file I get an error e.g.

> TS2339: Property 'username' does not exist on type 'JQuery'.

An example of when I get the error is:

```
 cy.fixture("details").as("details");

    cy.get("@details").then((users) => {
      const user: string = users.username;
```

I can get it to run if I make users of type any e.g.

> .then((users: any)

but I know that's not a good way to get around it.

I've seen a couple of other questions with a similar error but I'm not sure how to get those solutions working with Cypress, can anyone suggest anything that might help?

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to define a type for your user structure, something like this:

```js
class User {
  username: string
}
```

After that you can reference this type when you request the alias value (notice the **get<User>** expression):

```js
    cy.get<User>("@details").then((users) => {
          const user = users.username;
    }
```

Comment: may I ask where you get this info from other than checking type definition sources? It works, I just wonder if there are any docs beside official API definition on their website - because there is nothing said about `as<T>()` interface.

Comment: I do actually get this info from the type definition sources (just because I suspected it should be there). If you are interesting in the background knowledge, you may refer to the TS generics topic:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html

Answer (score 1):

In `cypress.d.ts` there's `interface Chainable` that includes this definition for the `get(alias)` syntax

```
/**
 * Get one or more DOM elements by alias.
 * @see https://on.cypress.io/get#Alias
 * @example
 *    // Get the aliased ‘todos’ elements
 *    cy.get('ul#todos').as('todos')
 *    //...hack hack hack...
 *    //later retrieve the todos
 *    cy.get('@todos')
 */
get<S = any>(alias: string, options?: Partial<Loggable & Timeoutable & Withinable & Shadow>): Chainable<S>
```

For some reason it's not picking up in tests, but you can patch it in

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />

// Add type definition in test file or /cypress/support/index.ts
declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable {
    get<S = any>(alias: string, options?: Partial<Loggable & Timeoutable & Withinable & Shadow>): Chainable<S>
  }
}

it('sees the get(alias) type def', () => {

  cy.fixture("example").as("details")   // using example fixture installed by Cypress

  cy.get("@details").then((user) => {
    const name: string = user.name  // no error
    const email: string = user.email  // no error
  })
})
```

---

If you just want to type as a generic object, use `Cypress.ObjectLike`, defined in `cypress.d.ts` as

```
interface ObjectLike {
  [key: string]: any
}
```

Use in test as

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />

cy.get<Cypress.ObjectLike>("@details").then((user) => {
  const name: string = user.username;
})
```

---

**Note**
The Cypress dfn for alias has generic type `get<S = any>`, so your solution `.then((users: any) =>` is pretty much equivalent.